# Updating multiple tables in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a function in codeigniter that i want to use to update two tables. This is the code

```
if($loss_making_trade_amount > 5 && $loss_making_trade_amount < 20){

                $user_data = array(
                   'trading_balance' => $trading_balance_float - 0.50
                     );

                    $data = array(
                   'trade_consequence' => '0.50',
                   'loss_in_amounts_cron_status' => 'seen'
                     );

                $where = "id='$rid'";
                $where_trading_balance = "email='$email'";

                $this->db->where($where);
                $this->db->set($data);
                $this->db->update('mailbox_ke_01', $data);
                //update users table at this level
                $this->db->where($where_trading_balance);
                $this->db->set($user_data);
                $this->db->update('users', $user_data);
}
```

Will i be able to update the tables in the way i have done or will `$this` be pointing to the first table when updating the second table?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, once a query ran - you don't have to be worry about because the Query Builder resets itself after every query if it is finished - or dies in case of a DB Error.

You can take a closer look [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1916)

The documentation also clearly suggests that the query runs if the update function gets called.

> `$this->db->update()` generates an update string and runs the query based on the data you supply.

For more information read the documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#updating-data)

---

The only thing i would change are your where clauses:

instead of

```
$where = "id='$rid'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

you should use the where function of the Querybuilder properly

```
$this->db->where("id", $rid);
```

The same applies for your `$where_trading_balance`